# Design a 12 V battery pack for portable electronics project

Tags: batteries, pcb, design, bms

I am doing some electronic project for a portable escape room business that I am running with my wife, the project are basically running or Arduino to take some inputs and switch on a 12 V solenoid which unlocks the portable box.

Up until now I am using the following:

Getting the 12 V from (8x1.5 V AA cells) this is used with a relay to power the solenoid.

The relay gets the on signal from an Arduino powered by a slim portable 5000 mAh battery using USB connection.

The setup works but I have an awful amount of wires inside and the reliability and maintenance of these boxes began to drive me crazy and this is when I decided that I want to learn how to design everything on a single PCB and utilize the inexpensive PCB manufacturing from china to manufacture these PCBs.

Now for most parts I got what I need except for the issue with power, I want to utilize 18650 Lithium-Ion batteries to power my projects I want to be able to deliver the required voltage levels of 12, 5, and 3.3 V from these batteries while able to charge them from outside the box without the need to remove the batteries or open the box.

For this I have tried the following:

- [18650 Battery Case Holder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWKGZXW)
- [Battery PCB Protection Board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JMY631D)
- Custom designed PCB that I solder the battery holders and the protection board onto.
- [Multi-Cell 3S Type-C To 12.6 V Step-Up Boost LiPo Polymer Li-Ion Charger 18650 Lithium Battery](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001380020220.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2nld)
- Some LDOs for the 5V and 3V3 powered from the 12 V output of the battery protection board output and powered the solenoid directly from the pack.

The combination works but I would like to design a single PCB with all these functionality and was wondering if you guys have a starting point to design a full battery management system that includes protection, balancing and charging and also be able to deliver power at the required levels.

Comment: The scope of your request is too broad for a question and answer site like this, but look at some of the semi manufacturers' websites for relevant reference designs and application notes.

Comment: Use a buck converter to get 5V from 12V. A linear regulator will convert nearly 60% of your battery charge to heat.

Comment: For each of the voltage rails you need, what is the current required?  Is it possible to eliminate the +12V rail and use relays/solenoids rated for lower voltage?  Why do you have both 5V and 3.3V, is it possible to eliminate one of these?

Comment: For an excellent  forum that supports discussion look at http://www.piclist.com (don't be put off by the presentation or the PIC in the name). Then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist, join the mailing list & say hello. Provide as much detail of your requirements as possible. (What you said here is a good start). 
 Just like here, there are people there who know almost everything (collectively). The site supports a conversational approach. Some SE members are also PICList members (myself included). It's a very useful complement to this site for questions of this sort.